# Receiving null values from Dapper QueryAsync returned cursor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, model, dapper

I’m having an issue with one of my dapper calls returning a cursor with all of the column data as `null`.

We have several calls that look identical to this one, which return a list of the provided model. I'm still getting familiar with C#, .Net, and Dapper, so there could be something simple that I'm missing.

Our SQL stored procedure expects:

```
Procedure ListItemGrid(pUserId     in number,
                       pListType   in varchar2,
                       pSearchTerm in varchar2,
                       pId         in varchar2,
                       pOut        out sys_refcursor
                       )
```

The Dapper call:

```cs
        public async Task<List<ListItem>> ListItemGrid(string id, string listType = null, string searchTerm = null)
        {
            using (var conn = this.GetConnection())
            {
                var p = new OracleDynamicParameters();
                p.Add("pUserId", value: this.userResolverService.UserId, dbType: OracleDbType.Double, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
                p.Add("pListType", value: listType, dbType: OracleDbType.Varchar2, size: 4000, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
                p.Add("pSearchTerm", value: searchTerm, dbType: OracleDbType.Varchar2, size: 4000, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
                p.Add("pId", value: id, dbType: OracleDbType.Varchar2, size: 4000, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
                p.AddCursor("pOut");

                var itemList = await conn.QueryAsync<ListItem>("SQL_PKG.ListItemGrid", param: p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                return itemList.AsList();
            }
        }
```

Where `SQL_PKG.ListItemGrid` returns a cursor of the same shape as the `ListItem` model:

```cs
using System;
using Proj.Name.Infrastructure.DataAccess;

namespace Proj.Name.Models
{
    public class ListItem
    {
        [Column("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Column("other_column")]
        public string other { get; set; }
        [Column("third_column")]
        public string third { get; set; }
        ...
    }
}
```

**Expected:** A list of `ListItem` with the values from our database.

```js
[
    {
      key: "string value",
      keyTwo: "other string value",
      ...
    },
    { ... },
    { ... }
]
```

**Actual:** A list of `ListItem` with correct length with the keys from `ListItem` but `null` for every value.

```js
[
    {
      key: null,
      keyTwo: null,
      ...
    },
    { ... },
    { ... }
]
```

**Why am I getting `null` for all of the values?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, changing:

```cs
using System;
using Proj.Name.Infrastructure.DataAccess;

namespace Proj.Name.Models
{
    public class ListItem
    {
        [Column("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Column("other_column")]
        public string other { get; set; }
        [Column("third_column")]
        public string third { get; set; }
        ...
    }
}
```

to **uppercase**:

```cs
using System;
using Proj.Name.Infrastructure.DataAccess;

namespace Proj.Name.Models
{
    public class ListItem
    {
        [Column("NAME")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Column("OTHER_COLUMN")]
        public string other { get; set; }
        [Column("THIRD_COLUMN")]
        public string third { get; set; }
        ...
    }
}
```

Fixed my issue.

This is still confusing, as our other models/dapper calls are working and lowercase. **If anyone has insight on why this is inconsistent, please let me know.**

**UPDATE:** I did not realize that `Column` was provided from a function we had written and was written in a way that was not case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by quoting from [this](http://www.alberton.info/dbms_identifiers_and_case_sensitivity.html) article:

> The SQL:2008 and SQL-99 standards define databases to be case
>   insensitive for identifiers unless they are quoted. Lower case
>   characters may be used in identifiers and keywords, but are considered
>   to be their upper case counterparts.

I see that you are using an Oracle database. Oracle complies with the above-mentioned standards. I cannot see your stored procedure definition, but if your stored procedure was defined with double-quotes around the field names, then they will be considered case-sensitive/uppercase. That could very well be the case.

So, your own solution uppercasing the columns names does make sense.